Basic question about 2-morphisms and homotopies
Say we are working in a category with an appropriate notion of homotopy between two morphisms given by 2-morphisms. When we say a diagram like the following

"commutes up to homotopy", what exactly are we saying? Is this just the statement that $a \circ c$ is homotopic to $b$, such that there would be a 2-morphism H filling the triangle as below?

Does the condition "commutes up to homotopy" say anything about the individual morphisms at all?

What reference are you reading? Do they use that phrase without a definition?

Yes, that's it. It means that the image of the diagram under the functor $\mathcal{C} \to ho(\mathcal{C})$ is commutative. What this precisely means depends on the context, though (what kind of categories are you working with? Please add a reference.).

Thank you. So to be clear, do you mean that the diagram needn't be commutative in C but will be in ho(C) under the image of your functor?
For the context, I'm actually looking at tangential structures on manifolds, which are diagrams of the second sort in my post (i.e. A would be a n-manifold M, B would be classifying space BG, C the classifying space BO(n)). Maybe that helps.

First question: yes. Second part: oh so you are just working in the category of topological spaces then? Then this is no serious higher categorical business.

In the previous comment, yes, but I also had in mind stratified spaces, constructed as in AFR17 (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01713).
